# Adding another parameter to the class renders code uncompilable

Tags: c++, c++11

I created a class extending a map-of-handlers collection, that does some tasks, according to reflexive arguments (it's an attempt to make a reflection for c++). However when I parameterized it to be not bound to a specific implementation, the compiler refused to work, showing strange error. Long things short, this compiles:

```
using namespace std;

template<class T>
class Blah {
public:
    using ctx_t = map<T, string>;

private:
    map<string, function<void(ctx_t&)>> handlers;

protected:
    void registerHandler(const string& name, function<void(ctx_t&)> fn) {
        handlers[name] = fn;
    }
};

class BlahDescendant : public Blah<string> {
public:
    BlahDescendant() {
        registerHandler("ala", [](ctx_t& m) {cout << m["ala"]; });
    }
};

int main() {
    BlahDescendant desc;
    return 0;
}
```

But when parameterized, it refuses to compile, saying that

```
testfield.cpp:33:35: error: 'ctx_t' has not been declared
```

.

```
using namespace std;

template<class T, class X>
class Blah {
public:
    using ctx_t = map<T, X>;

private:
    map<string, function<void(ctx_t&)>> handlers;

protected:
    void registerHandler(const string& name, function<void(ctx_t&)> fn) {
        handlers[name] = fn;
    }
};

template<class X>
class BlahDescendant : public Blah<string, X> {
public:
    BlahDescendant() {
        registerHandler("ala", [](ctx_t& m) {cout << m["ala"]; });
    }
};

int main() {
    BlahDescendant<string> desc;
    return 0;
}
```

When trying to give map in lambdas there is different error reported:

```
error: 'registerHandler' was not declared in this scope, and no declarations were found by argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation [-fpermissive]
     registerHandler("ala", [](map<string,X>& m) {cout << m["ala"]; });
```

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the definition of a class template or a member of a class template, if a base class of the class template depends on a template-parameter, the base class scope is not examined during unqualified name lookup either at the point of definition of the class template or member or during an instantiation of the class template or member.

So you need to tell compiler, that your type ctx_t is from Blah, so you need either

```
[](typename Blah<string,X>::ctx_t& m) {cout << m["ala"]; }
```

or

```
template<class X>
class BlahDescendant : public Blah<string, X> {
public:
    using ctx_t = typename Blah<string,X>::ctx_t;
};
```

registerHandler is also non dependent name, so you need to make it dependent on BlahDescendant and Blah scopes using **this** explicitly

```
template<class X>
class BlahDescendant : public Blah<string, X> {
public:
    using ctx_t = typename Blah<string,X>::ctx_t;
    BlahDescendant() {
         this->registerHandler("ala", [](ctx_t& m) {cout << m["ala"]; });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BlahDescendant() {
    this->registerHandler("ala", [](auto& m) {cout << m["ala"]; });
}
```

When accessing a member of a base class of a template class, you need to use `this->` explicitly.

If you want to type that lambda explicitly, you need `typename`, as the type is defined in the class template:

```
[](typename Blah<string, X>::ctx_t& m) { ...
```

Comment: I might have said something wrong here, but I don't see anything obvious, so I'd be glad if the downvoter commented as well.

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but probably you've got a downvote because it's not working in C++11 (better auto functionalities are in c++14 I guess?). Also the version with typename Blah<string,X>::ctx_t& does not look good.

Comment: @pawel_j Weird, considering the latest standard is C++17. And I don't know what do you mean by *does not look good*, because, well, at least [it works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f845e583802d2d24).

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz, question is marked with c++11 tag.

Comment: @DanielVlasenko Oops, I missed that part. Well, my answer covers both, anyway.